# Selenium - How to open new Chrome Window, using Javascript Executors

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have an edit button on a page. I want to open this in a new window.

At the moment, this code will click the edit button and have it open in the default window:

```
    Actions actions = new Actions(driver);      
    JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;       
    actions.moveToElement(elem1).click();
    jse.executeScript("arguments[0].click()", elem1);
```

To open it in another window, I tried doing something like

```
Actions newwin = new Actions(driver);
newwin.keyDown(Keys.SHIFT).click(elem1).keyUp(Keys.SHIFT).build().perform();
```

However, this returns an error, because it's not actually moving to the element and finding it. If I scroll down to where the edit button is manually while my script is running, the edit page will get opened in a new window, as wanted.
However, I don't want to manually have to scroll down to the edit button every time I run my Selenium script.

I tried doing something like this:

`Actions newwin = new Actions(driver);       newwin.moveToElement(elem1).keyDown(Keys.SHIFT).click(elem1).keyUp(Keys.SHIFT).build().perform();`

But it still was not able to select the edit element and open it in a new window.

Does anyone have any ideas how I can make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay got it guys..

I needed to scroll it into view first, then I could right click and open it in a new window

I was having issues because I really wanted to do it in 1 step, but I broke it down into 2:

```
        ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", 
elem1);
    Thread.sleep(500); 

    Actions newwin = new Actions(driver);
    newwin.keyDown(Keys.SHIFT).click(elem1).keyUp(Keys.SHIFT).build().perform();
```

Answer (score 1):

you already said its not scrolling down. so that is the source of your problem. 
you dont need to create another action for this if you just want a new window.

```
window.onload = function() {
document.getElementById("actualID").onclick = function(){
    return !window.open(this.href, "actualID", "width=666,height=666");
}
```

-with your existing code, can you print to console the position of elements to 
confirm that the edit button can actually be seen (in the DOM)...debugging.

-use CSS or ID for your locator first then try others.

you can you create an event and wrap it into a promise and make this cleaner.

Comment: Thanks for the reply -- how would the above code snippet look like in Java? Thanks

Comment: you can wrap it in JavascriptExecutor. looks like you already figured it out though :)